# rearrange layouts of two templates

Tags: template, layout, theme

I am new to magento. I installed "perfume" theme from magento connect. I want to rearrange two templates in the home page which have names as follows:

- frontend\base\default\template\page/template/links.phtml
- frontend\base\default\template\page/switch/languages.phtml

---

[image]

---

To do so,  I created a `local.xml` file in `app/design/frontend/default/perfume/layout` directory structure and added the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
          <remove name="footer_links"/>
          <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml" before="store_language"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

But still I can't see any change in the frontend. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml` on line 105 you'll find the `footer_links` that you are referencing. This one is wrapped in the block `footer` (line 99)

So that means that the `root` reference should actually be `footer`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="footer">
          <remove name="footer_links"/>
          <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml" before="store_language"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

As far as I can tell the only thing you've changed is the `before` attribute.
Although I haven't tested it you could try and do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="footer_links">
            <action method="setAttribute"><key>before</key><value>store_language</value></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

But again, I'm not 100% sure that works so let me know if you try it.

Comment: yeah sure I will let you know. Thanks. I am trying now.

Comment: I have tried both ways. no changes.. there are no console errors.

Comment: actually as far as I can see in the default footer in page.xml there is no `store_language` only a `store_switcher`. Did you include the `store_language` yourself?

Comment: Hey, I just realized that `languages.phtml` is in `header` parent block whereas `links.phtml` is in `footer` parent block. does it has to do something?

Comment: no, I haven't included. maybe the theme "perfume" included it. please check the image for better understanding.

Comment: hm in that case look in the layout files where it is included and under what name, also check if it isn't called statically using `$this->getChildHtml('store_language');` or maybe the positioning is done using CSS. there are a LOT of options on how this could be done

Comment: it is being called like `getChildHtml('store_language')` in `base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml`. what should I do then? can you please come to [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7214/magento) if you ok..